# Issue formatting string in xcode iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, string, format, viewdidload

I'm a noob to iphone development (2nd day using xcode) and I am having trouble making a dynamic text for a label.  My string:

```
dealerspremiumLabel.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%% (%@%d)", premiumPercentage, symbol, premiumCurrency];
```

is returning as "0% ((null)88988)" instead of "0% ($00.00)".  I can't figure out why this is happening because in ViewDidLoad I set my variables as:

```
premiumPercentage=0;
premiumCurrency= 00.00;
symbol=@"$";
dealerspremiumLabel.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%% (%@%d)", premiumPercentage, symbol, premiumCurrency];
```

My label outlet is properly set and my variables are setup properly as well. I also have checked my Log and the values for these particular variables are set correctly before the above code.  Any help figuring this out is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `symbol` is useless, just put the `$` directly into your format definition: `%d% ($%d)`.  Otherwise try `%s` instead of `%@`.

Comment: thanks, but that didn't work for symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this way,

currency is float you are using %d instead of %f

```
dealerspremiumLabel.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%% (%@%.2f)", premiumPercentage, symbol, premiumCurrency];
```

EDIT:

As your `symbol` is giving `null`, you have missed to alloc+init.

Or you can directly use :

```
dealerspremiumLabel.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%% ($%.2f)", premiumPercentage,  premiumCurrency];
```

Comment: That fixed currency, but I'm still getting a null for symbol.

Comment: `symbol` looks like an NSString, if he has alloc+init-ed it should not show `null`

Comment: I just changed to 
dealerspremiumLabel.text= [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%d%% ($%.2f)", premiumPercentage,  premiumCurrency];
but its still not working.

Comment: no error in symbol, NSLog is showing correct value. This is becoming frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

```
   NSInteger premiumPercentage=0;

  CGFloat premiumCurrency= 00.00;

  NSString *symbol1=@"$";

  symbol.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%% (%@%f)", premiumPercentage,symbol1,premiumCurrency];

  NSLog(@"text=%@",symbol.text);
```

I used this one and its working perfectly fine in my case and its also showing correct value in UILabel